# Insanely simple angular/node app not working as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

I made the most simple possible application using angular and node. It is a chat application that has an ng-model on a text field.

When the text field value changes, the message is emitted and node sends it out. I assign that value to a variable, but it is always one character behind. I honestly have no idea why.

For example, the text field value is "hello world", and the {{receive}} prints out "hello worl".

What's worse is when I console.log the data it has the full value, I assign it immediately after without altering it at all, and it is missing a character. Am I doing something wrong?

```
<p>{{receive}}</p>
<input ng-model="msg"></input>
<script>

var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('chat', ['$scope',

function($scope) {
   var socket = io.connect();
    $scope.msg = '';
    $scope.receive = '';

        $scope.$watch('msg',function(){
            socket.emit('send message', $scope.msg);
        });

        socket.on('new message', function(data){
            console.log(data);
            // console.logging results in the entire message
            $scope.receive = data;
        });

}]);

</script>

var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(3000);

app.get('/', function(request, response){
    response.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){

    socket.on('send message', function(data){
        io.sockets.emit('new message', data);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$scope.$apply` to update your bindings when changing it outside of an Angular function.

```
socket.on('new message', function(data){
    console.log(data);
    // console.logging results in the entire message
    $scope.receive = data;
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

It can also be used like this, which captures any errors thrown inside the function and updates anyway.

```
socket.on('new message', function(data){
    console.log(data);
    // console.logging results in the entire message
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.receive = data;
    });
});
```

Comment: This fixed it, thanks, i'm unfamiliar with angular and node. Will accept your answer when the timer is up. Just out of curiosity, why the 1 character delay?

Comment: @JosueEspinosa The `$scope.$watch` is called every time you type a character, and it will update the bindings. So there's an update every time you type a character, but the update is done with whatever message you have received from the server at that point, which with minimal latency will be 1 character short.